# How to get cURL information

Tags: php, curl

I have a cURL script that makes connection to a page:

```
<?php 
// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init(); 

// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com"); 

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 

// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);      
?>
```

And that page gives an output like:

```
{
  "status" : "fail",
  "data" : {
    "error_message" : "Destination address 37428963298746238 is invalid for Network=BTC."
  }
}
```

How do I get "error_message" to `$error_message` with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you: Pass your output to `json_decode`

```
<?php

$json = '{
  "status" : "fail",
  "data" : {
    "error_message" : "Destination address 37428963298746238 is invalid for Network=BTC."
  }
}';




$obj = json_decode($json);



foreach($obj as $value){

echo $value->error_message;

}

?>
```

http://codepad.org/hiDYWlxR

Answer (score 2):

You can get error like that:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 

// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com"); 

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 

// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);   
$error = json_decode($output);   
dd($error);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // create curl resource 
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    // set url 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com"); 

    //return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    if(curl_error($ch))
    {
        echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }

    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    curl_close($ch);
```